# Import multiple Tables to one CSV file with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to export a csv file but im having issues pulling 2 colums that are on 2 different tables

I have a main table that has lots of the data that i need but in two colums it needs to come from other SQL table.

```
case "exemple":
    if(isset($_COOKIE["sqsp_logged_in"]) != true){ 
        die("<p style='color:#000; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width: 100%; font-size: 1em;'>You do not have access to this data.</p>"); 
    } else { 
        $Status = "Exporting data...";
        $SQL_Query = "SELECT `engagement_number`,`program`,`year`,`companyname`,`initiative`, `engagement_title`,`resolution_url`,`status_notes`,`status`,`engagement_type` FROM `company_resolutions`;";
        $Initiatives->exportMysqlToCsv($SQL_Query, 'engagements.csv', $mysqli);
    } 
break;
```

But the issue is that `companyname` and `initiative` are in two differnt tables

ive trying doing multiple selects but wont work like

```
$SQL_Query = "SELECT `engagement_number`,`program`,`year`,`companyname`, `engagement_title`,`resolution_url`,`status_notes`,`status`,`engagement_type` FROM `company_resolutions`;
        SELECT `name` FROM `companies`;
        SELECT `name` FROM `res_initiatives`;";
```

any ideas?

Comment: Read up on `JOIN` in the SQL language. Solving requirements like yours is **the entire purpose** of relational databases. Worth every minute you spend learning about it.

Comment: Thanks, im trying to use the join statement now ill let you know if works!